# Gettings records by cureent date,week, and month in php mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the records per current day, week and month in php mysql. The date column is of date type. The issue is here is that my week records and months records are getting same from below script. Here is my code, have a look.

```
public function getTodayComing(){
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');
    $sql = "select * from bookings,bookers where ";
    $qualifier = ' bookings.booker_id = bookers.id 
                  AND ((status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['APPROVE'].'" 
                  OR status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['RESCHEDULED'].'" 
                  OR status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['RECONSULTED'].'") 
                  AND date=DATE( NOW() ))
                  ORDER BY date ASC';

    $sql. = $qualifier;     
    return  $valuearray = $connection->getArray ($sql );        
}
public function getWeekComing() {
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');
    $sql = "select * from bookings,bookers where ";
    $qualifier = ' bookings.booker_id = bookers.id 
                   AND ((status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['APPROVE'].'" 
                   OR status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['RESCHEDULED'].'" 
                   OR status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['RECONSULTED'].'") 
                   AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) ORDER BY date ASC';
    $sql. = $qualifier;
    return  $valuearray = $connection->getArray( $sql );
}
public function getMonthComing() {
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');
    $sql = "select * from bookings,bookers where ";
    $qualifier = ' bookings.booker_id = bookers.id 
                   AND ((status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['APPROVE'].'" 
                   OR status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['RESCHEDULED'].'" 
                   OR status ="'.AppGlobal::$bookingStatus['RECONSULTED'].'") 
                   AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) ORDER BY date ASC';
    $sql. = $qualifier;
    return  $valuearray = $connection->getArray( $sql );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data for more than a week, can you try querying with a date that is about a month old and ensure this

Comment: `DATE_SUB(CUR_DATE(), ...)` would make more sence. And \`date\`.

Comment: @JoopEggen ANY IDEA how to get correct records?

Comment: No real idea, try `bookings.date`. In general: `SELECT * FROM bookings JOIN bookers ON bookers.id = bookings.booker_id WHERE` would be more "sophisticated." Likewise `date = CUR_DATE()`. Are you sure records exist, booker_id is filled in?

Answer (score 0):

Aah, I just saw it I think

```
date > DATE_SUB(...)
```

should be

```
date BETWEEN CUR_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CUR_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 ...)
```